# Confusion in options of integration

Tags: integration

> If
>   $$
> I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan(ax)-\arctan(x)}{x}\,\mathrm dx,
> $$
>   then

- (A) $I'(1),I'(2),I'(3)$ are in harmonic progression.
- (B) $I'(2)=\dfrac\pi4$
- (C) $I(\pi)=\dfrac\pi2\log\pi$
- (D) $I'(3)=\dfrac\pi6$

In this question the derivative of I should be zero as RHS of a $I$ is constant .

But the answer is given as $A,B,C,D$

Comment: what is $I$ in your question?

Comment: @Dr.MV harmonic progression

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Note that $I(a)$ is a function of $a$.  Therefore, we can differentiate under the integral to obtain

$$\begin{align}
I'(a)&=\frac{d}{da}\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(ax)-\arctan(x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial a}\left(\frac{\arctan(ax)-\arctan(x)}{x}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+(ax)^2}\,dx\tag 1\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2a}\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Then, using $I(1)=0$, we find after integrating $(2)$ that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{I(a)=\frac{\pi \log(a)}{2}}\tag 3$$

Then, we see from $(2)$ and $(3)$ that all choices (A), (B), (C), and (D) are true.

---

**NOTE:**

> The uniform convergence of the integral in $(1)$ for $|a|\ge \delta>0$ (coupled with the convergence of $I(a)$ for all $a\ne0$) guarantees the legitimacy of differentiating under the integral sign.

Answer (score 7):

Note that the conditions of Frullani's Integral are met with $f(x)=\arctan(x)$. So, your integral is just $$\lim_{b\to\infty}(\arctan(b)-0)\ln(a)=\boxed{\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\ln(a)}$$
Now, consider your options.

Comment: What is Frullani's integral

Comment: See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html

Comment: @search where did you find this problem?

Comment: This was given by my school